MudDataGrid filterable row and column menu not working
I'm using mudDataGrid to display my data (IEnumerable), It works fine.
I've also enable filterable to filter columns, But both filter row and column menu not working!
The filter row is disabled (read-only) and in the column menu, The operator list is empty and does not have value field! (see my attached image).

Here is my code :
<MudDataGrid T="DataRow" Items="this._lstRows" Filterable="true" FilterMode="DataGridFilterMode.ColumnFilterRow" QuickFilter="@FilterFunc">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="persianFontSans">@Report.ReportPersianName</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="_searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="MudBlazor.Size.Medium" Class="mt-0 persianFontSans"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <Columns>
        @foreach (var dc in this.Data.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>())
        {
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x[dc.ColumnName]" Title="@dc.ColumnName" HeaderClass="persianFontSans" CellClass="persianFontSans"
                            Format="@GetFormatString(dc)" />
        }
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="DataRow" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>

Where is the problem and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Could you post more codes about the relevant parameters?

What does "DataRow" looks like.

I have a method which executed some reports (based on user selected) and returned a dataTable which have a different columns according to selected report. Hence, the given dataSource (dataTable) does not have fix columns. Now the Items property of my mudDataGrid bound to datatable.AsEnumerable() (_lstRows)

appearently, if i bind mudDataGrid to dataTable, IEnumerable and IEnumerable, The filter options not working (filterRow and columMenu)! Can anybody help me how to work-around this?

PropertyColumn is not designed for dynamic scenarios like ExpandoObject. It's strictly for models where the properties are known at design time, i.e., strongly typed models, not for use cases involving a foreach loop.
It can't determine the type for expressions like x => x[dc.ColumnName]. You need to write your own Column analogous to this code but without using expressions, where you can supply the type in a different way.
For example, if you want to use DataColumn, you could do something like this:
<MudDataGrid T="DataRow" Items="@Rows" Filterable="true">
    <Columns>
        @foreach (var dc in Columns)
        {
            <DynamicColumn Content="x => x[dc.ColumnName]" DataType="@dc.DataType" Title="@dc.ColumnName" />
        }
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code 
{
    private static IEnumerable<DataColumn> Columns = GetTable().Columns.OfType<DataColumn>();

    private static IEnumerable<DataRow> Rows = GetTable().Rows.OfType<DataRow>();


    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Sign", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Molar", typeof(double));

        // Add rows.
        table.Rows.Add(1, "H", "Hydrogen", 0, 1.00794d);
        table.Rows.Add(2, "He", "Helium", 17, 4.002602d);
        table.Rows.Add(3, "Li", "Lithium", 0, 6.941d);
        table.Rows.Add(4, "Be", "Beryllium", 1, 9.012182d);

        return table;
    }
}

public partial class DynamicColumn<T> : Column<T>
{
    [Parameter]
    public Type DataType { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<T, object> Content { get; set; }

    protected internal override object CellContent(T item) => Content?.Invoke(item);

    protected internal override object PropertyFunc(T item) => null;

    protected internal override void SetProperty(object item, object value)
    {
        
    }

    protected internal override Type PropertyType => DataType;
}

Keep in mind that this is just an example and not a full implementation. This shows how you could make the filter operators work, but if you want to edit a row, you need to provide your own implementation of SetProperty.

Thanks for your answer. Yes, this activate filter row, But not working (filtering not affected)!

As I said, this is not a full implementation but rather just an example to guide you. For example, to enable sorting, you need to implement override string PropertyName. For filtering, you need to implement override LambdaExpression PropertyExpression. You could use the Content property for it, but then another challenge awaits you since the default FilterExpressionGenerator doesn't work with DataTable. You need to provide own IFilterDefinition implementation and supply the new implementation via SetDefaultFilterDefinition in the DataGrid. This will take some hours to program.

Hi again! Could you please tell me where can i find this documentation about how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance
